# how to enable the telemetry for nginx ingress controller in kubernetes (ACE) for application insights?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, containers, azure-application-insights, nginx-ingress

I have set of microservices running in k8 cluster and logging enabled for Application insights via source codes java. I would like to add ngnix controller also to application insights so that when it scales up I can track through Application Insights.

Comment: Have you tried Prometheus? https://prometheus.io/

Comment: No, my requirement is to add to App Insights.

Comment: Please check this out - https://github.com/jjjordanmsft/ApplicationInsights-logforward